# Blind Date and Times

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, time

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Monthly Topic Challenge #6: Is it really that [time] again?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7431/monthly-topic-challenge-6-is-it-really-that-time-again?cb=1).</sub>

---

I was going on a blind date with a fellow puzzler and they sent me this:

[image: Text Message Conversation]

I didn't end up going on the date, got mixed messages. But if I did, how might I have recognized them?

---

Transcript:

```
A: Ok, so the pier it is then! When should we meet?

B: I can do exclusively 1:17 or 7:56 or 6:21

B: Hopefully that doesn't raise any red flags

A: That works, and how will I recognize you?

B: I'll wear a distinctive three letter accessory.
   If you're my age and as good a puzzler as you say,
   you should be able to figure it out :)

A: I knew I shouldn't have expected a straight answer
```

Comment: So I assumed I was missing another step. That's why I deleted my answer, if you are wondering.

Comment: @ACB - gotcha :) yours was certainly *a* correct answer, but my date was so unwilling to give a straight answer that it could be solved another way too. I guess they were worried I'd be too old?

Answer (score 1):

Your partner will wear a

> **WIG**.

Looking at the times they gave you,

> we can make three clock faces. Then as hinted by red flags, we decode them as flag semaphore.
>
>  [image: W][image: I][image: G]
>
>  which gives the three letter word 'wig'.

However, I am not sure how you can recognize that, unless I am missing something in the message. But since you're their age and good a puzzler, you will be able to figure it out.

Comment: They might have worn that! But they were just so unwilling to give a straight answer ... :p